# M2M relation Django, with custom intermediate table having an extra field

Tags: django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have two models like CinicHospital and Doctor with M2M relationship. The custom intermediate table is created because I need an extra field.

```
class DoctorHospital(models.Model):
clinic = models.ForeignKey(ClinicHospital, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
doctor = models.ForeignKey(Doctor, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
shift = models.CharField(max_length = 10)
```

**Problem** in this DoctorHospital model two fields are auto-filled while creating ClinicHospital and Doctor but I'm trouble to fill the shift field.
Could I combine this shift field in doctor form and save it in intermediate table?

Comment: Why not make a view that takes as `model = DoctorHospital`? In that case you select the `ClinicHospital`, the `Doctor`, and the `shift`.

Comment: yes, It could be and it is easy for me as well. it's not good I mention the shift while creating a doctor?